# AWS - Create a record set for an s3 static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static website up and running at

http://volcalc.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/

It is stored on an aws S3 bucket.

I have bought the domain volcalc.io

I just want to switch to use that as the url of my website.

I'm following the instructions here. I'm doing "Create record sets".

I'm trying to create a record set but when I check the radio button "yes" for "alias" then I try to enter an "alias target" there are no options to select from and the tutorial is saying there should be:

[image]

So I just tried to paste in this: http://volcalc.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/

and click create but it says:

> The record set could not be saved because:
>   - Alias Target contains an invalid value.

What do I enter into alias target? Why aren't there any options to select from?

Comment: I think you need to set A record where you brought `volcalc.io` to point to S3 public IP, so that `volcalc.io` will point to right place.

Comment: I found that the endpoint becomes available in the dropdown menu if the domain record is the same as the domain in s3

Answer (score 36):

I know you might have solved the issue, but for the people who see this post:

If you cannot find the endpoint on the list, simply copy and paste it there.

Also you would need to remove the bucket name from your end point.

only input this part:  **s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/**

Route 53 will find a bucket that has your exact domain name.

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks for this one.

Comment: This is not correct. If I enter s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com it is not found.

Comment: @alex is your s3 in the same region as the route 53?

Comment: Yep! @ArmanFatahi - I got it to work. I guess it just takes awhile for the repo to show up in the Route53 end. In my case, it was about 2.5hrs.

Comment: This is the keyword: 'Route 53 will find a bucket that has your exact domain name'.

Comment: super helpful!  

The official document did not mention this critical point 

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/

Answer (score 6):

Steps required:

- Create a bucket with the name of the desired domain (eg A bucket called `volcalc.io`)
- Turn on **Static Website hosting**
- Create a Route 53 record set with `Alias=Yes` and select the static website from above

See: [Routing Traffic to a Website that Is Hosted in an Amazon S3 Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html)

Comment: "Create a bucket with the name of the desired domain (eg A bucket called volcalc.io)" that's what I have done wrong. I really don't understand why aws made it must be setup in way. Something like xxx.yourmain.com => xxx s3 arn would be more straight forward

Answer (score 6):

You will need to point your alias record to the resource, not the endpoint :

ALIAS : s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: The AWS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-add-arecord-to-hostedzone states incorrectly to "Type the name of your Amazon S3 bucket endpoint, for example http://example.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com."

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to create the record but your s3 bucket is not showing up,
check that the bucket name matches the name of the subdomain / domain you are trying to setup.

For example, if my subdomain is `www.passioncloud.net` then I must make sure the name of my bucket is also `www.passioncloud.net` .

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html